# CalendarView ограничение возможности выбора дат

Tags: java, android, android-studio, datepicker, calendar-view

*Подскажите новенькому в Android Studio*

Получаю в приложение данные в виде "dd.mm.yyyy" например:

> 22.09.2017
>   23.09.2017
>   24.09.2017
>   26.09.2017
>   27.09.2017
>   29.09.2017
>   30.09.2017

Как видно выше, отсутствуют даты 25,28

Необходимо, чтобы CalendarView показал доступные для выбора даты "22,23,24,26,27,29,30", а все остальные(не входящие в список) были не доступны для выбора.

Должно получиться как на изображении ниже.

[image: Должно получиться так.]
Возможно это решается через другой компонент?

Answer (score 1):

В стандартном компоненте нет такой возможности. Либо пишите свой, либо найдите что-то подходящее, созданное другими, к примеру

https://github.com/wdullaer/MaterialDateTimePicker

Имеет методы `setDisabledDays(Calendar[] days)` и `setDisabledTimes(Timepoint[] times)`.